# Mysterious error with XML in Google Merchants

Tags: xml, upload, virtuemart

I've written an exporter in php extrancting data from mysql db. Tags are appropriate, the structure is I hope valid, but smeg [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smeg_(vulgarism)#Smeg) knows why (I couldn't find a fault) it doens't want to consume a link from XML pointing to my product in shop. It says: Error of formating XML. The system couldn't process the source [2](http://stepolabs.com/lab/stuff/error.png). I'm adding a picture.

Does anyone have an experience with this type of problem?
Thank you for you advices!

Stepo

Comment: from the picture it looks like there is & character in your xml. & in the xml denote an entity and the entity in Xml files look like &{name}; (e.g. &quot;). From the picture it looks to me that the parser is expecting ';' which would define &flypage; entity. Obviously this is not the intent here. Ale the & should be written as &amp; in the Xml file - e.g. ...&amp;flypage=...

Comment: Hi! It's too late. Tomorrow, I'll try it and inform you about my progress! This is 1st time I'm doing this, so I'm glad that you advised me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the picture it looks like there is & character in your xml. & in the xml denote an entity and the entity in Xml files look like &{name}; (e.g. "). From the picture it looks to me that the parser is expecting ';' which would define &flypage; entity. Obviously this is not the intent here. Ale the & should be written as & in the Xml file - e.g. ...&flypage=...